# How to get first column of an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm using a csv file as input data for my model. I'm using pandas dataframe to choose desired column of it as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
     dataframe = pd.read_csv(f)

X = dataframe.iloc[:,(0,1)]
y = dataframe.iloc[:,(2)]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Then I'd like to extract first column from X_test array. How is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use `X_test.ix[:,0]` and you can omit `with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:`  or if `X_test` is numpy array - `X_test[:,0]`

Comment: I think the best is add sample to your question - what is output of function `train_test_split(X, y)` ?

Comment: X_test.ix[:,0] works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @jezrael It splits X and y into two categories of train and test data for modeling purposes. If you are interested, you can read here more: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and omit `with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:`, because [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can read file by `path of file`.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X = dataframe.iloc[:,(0,1)]
y = dataframe.iloc[:,(2)]:

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

X_test.ix[:,0]
```